# Can't get my if else to work properly

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm currently working on a personal project & i can't really understand why the application won't tell the user when something is wrong.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connect;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USERS (Namn,Personnummer,Username,Password,accountid,Avtal,Startdatum) values(@parameter1,@parameter2,@parameter3,@parameter4,@parameter5,@parameter6,@parameter7)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter1", (textBox1.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter2", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter3", (textBox3.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter4", (textBox4.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter5", textBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter6", (textBox6.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter7", (textBox7.Text));
            MySqlDataReader accessed = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Account created!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong, could'nt establish a stable connection");
        }
}
```

As for it is now, the application just crash if a stable connection can't start, and won't tell the user the messagebox part.

Comment: Why do you leave the connection open at all? Don't do that. Instead use the `using`-statement to always close the connection as soon as possible in the method. Note that closing a connection makes it available to be reused, it isn't closed physically with connection-pooling.

Comment: Use a try catch block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try{
    if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USERS (Namn,Personnummer,Username,Password,accountid,Avtal,Startdatum) values(@parameter1,@parameter2,@parameter3,@parameter4,@parameter5,@parameter6,@parameter7)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter1", (textBox1.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter2", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter3", (textBox3.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter4", (textBox4.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter5", textBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter6", (textBox6.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter7", (textBox7.Text));
        MySqlDataReader accessed = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Account created!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong, could'nt establish a stable connection");
    }
  }
catch
{
      MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong, could'nt establish a stable connection");
}
}
```

You can handle `Catch` in various ways. get the exact errors. Like:

```
try{}
catch(Exception ex)
{MessageBox.Show(ex.message);}
```

[MSDN link for try catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) you may find any other way appropriate.

Comment: You're a star! Thank you so much :)

Comment: As stated by Tim Schmelter, why is the connection left open? Using the using statement you won't require the need for the if and else, only the try and catch.

Comment: If exceptions are being thrown, there is some underlying issue. I think it'd be better to address that issue than to just wrap things up in a try-catch. Just my opinion...

Comment: @OliverNicholls it depends on the situation, I think. in most case, I throw errors to know exactly what error is occuring.

Comment: @Chawin Its always best using "USING". But how can I suggest him? in this event he is doing work, if the connectionstate is open. that means, the connection should be open.